# Problem with callout button and firestore in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mapkit, mkannotation

I have 5 collections on Firestore. With the data of the documents of those collections, I create annotations of different types and display them on a map view.

The problem is that I want to pass all the information that is stored in each annotation and display it on another view controller, that appears when you press the callout button.

I can't figure out a way of referencing the annotation I'm pressing and then pass the data to the other screen.

This is my first time using databases and I don't have many experience, so I would appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a Firestore problem, this is a map problem.

Comment: @bsod Not even sure that's a map problem; *then pass the data to the other screen* Passing data within your app is a fundamental coding process. We would really need to see the code you've attempted and by what process you want to 'pass' the data. A Segue? A delegate? A child instance? A parent/child setup? Something else? Please clarify the question and take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to give a specific answer since I don't know the full scope of your features. But this is how you generally do it.

First when you create the `MKAnnotation` subclass, you define a property to hold an object that you can reference later. For example, say I'm showing restaurants and supermarkets in a map.

```
class RestaurantAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    let restaurant: Restaurant
    
    var title: String? {
        return restaurant.name
    }
    
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return restaurant.coordinate
    }
    
    init(restaurant: Restaurant) {
        self.restaurant = restaurant
        super.init()
    }
}

struct Restaurant {
    let name: String
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}
```

Same goes for the supermarkets.

Then when you create the annotation, you pass the `Restaurant` object to it.

```
let restaurant = Restaurant(name: "McDonald's", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 27.2831, longitude: -127.831))
let restaurantAnnotation = RestaurantAnnotation(restaurant: restaurant)
mapView.addAnnotation(restaurantAnnotation)
```

You implement the [mapView(_:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1616211-mapview) delegate method to be notified when the user taps on the callout button in annotations. In it, you can easily reference the object you passed to it earlier.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    if let annotation = view.annotation as? RestaurantAnnotation {
        print(annotation.restaurant)
    } else if let annotation = view.annotation as? SupermarketAnnotation {
        print(annotation.supermarket)
    }
}
```

And you can use that data to do whatever you want after that. In your case, pass it to a new screen.

Comment: I may not be understanding the question as it's a bit vague, but I think the question asks about passing data between view controllers *The problem is that I want to pass all the information that is stored in each annotation and display it on another view controller* not necessarily adding an annotation to a specific viewController.

Comment: @Jay Yes, I agree. Seems like the OP already has the showing annotations part figured out but don't know how to reference each annotation. I showed how to do that in the last code excerpt n the answer. Just added the showing annotations to give it more context.